# Host nginx TLS <- Docker nginx passthrough

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, tls1.2

I've got a number of Docker containers running under Docker-compose in an Ubuntu host VPS. One of the containers is a Nginx load balancer / reverse proxy sitting on port 12000 and defined as follows:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    upstream backend {
        server fhback:8000;
    }

    upstream frontend {
        server fhfront:8090;
    }

    upstream centrifugo {
        server centrifugo:9998;
    }

    upstream centrifugo-admin {
        server centrifugo:9997;
    }

    upstream pgadmin {
        server pgadmin:5050;
    }

    upstream prometheus {
        server prometheus:9090;
    }

    upstream grafana {
        server grafana:3000;
    }
    
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
        "text/html"                 epoch; # set this to your needs
        "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch; # set this to your needs
        default                     off;   # set this to your needs
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     localhost 127.0.0.1;

        gzip            on;
        gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript application/json;
        gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_min_length 1000;

        charset                                   utf-8;     
        include                                   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        client_max_body_size                      20M;

        location /connection/ws {
            proxy_pass                            http://centrifugo;
            proxy_http_version                    1.1;
            proxy_redirect                        default;
            proxy_buffering                       off;
            keepalive_timeout                     65;   
            proxy_set_header                      Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                      Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header                      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_read_timeout                    60s;
            proxy_connect_timeout                 60s;
            proxy_cache_bypass                    $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /connection/admin {
            proxy_pass                            http://centrifugo-admin;
            proxy_http_version                    1.1;
            proxy_redirect                        default;
            proxy_set_header                      Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                      Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header                      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass                            http://backend;
            proxy_http_version                    1.1;
            proxy_redirect                        default;
            proxy_set_header                      Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                      Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header                      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_read_timeout                    1800;
            proxy_connect_timeout                 1800;
            sendfile                              on;
            tcp_nopush                            on;
            sendfile_max_chunk                    20M;
        }

        location /pgadmin {
            proxy_pass                            http://pgadmin;
            proxy_http_version                    1.1;
            proxy_redirect                        default;
            proxy_set_header                      Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                      Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header                      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_read_timeout                    1800;
            proxy_connect_timeout                 1800;
            sendfile                              on;
            tcp_nopush                            on;
            sendfile_max_chunk                    20M;
        }

        location /prometheus {
            proxy_pass                            http://prometheus;
            proxy_http_version                    1.1;
            proxy_redirect                        default;
            proxy_set_header                      Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                      Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header                      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /grafana {
            proxy_pass                            http://grafana;
            proxy_http_version                    1.1;
            proxy_redirect                        default;
            proxy_set_header                      Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                      Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header                      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass                            http://frontend;
            proxy_http_version                    1.1;
            proxy_redirect                        default;
            proxy_set_header                      Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                      Connection       "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header                      Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header                      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            root                                  /app/dist;
            expires                               $expires;
            index                                 index.html index.htm;
            try_files                             $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
}
```

So basically it opens specific locations for the other containers on the specified ports.

Now the HOST nginx adds TLS for all traffic as follows (/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf):

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name my-domain.site www.my-domain.site;

    keepalive_timeout      70;
    ssl_certificate        /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.site/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.site/chain.pem;
    ssl_protocols          TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers            "RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH";
    ssl_stapling           on;
    ssl_stapling_verify    on;
    resolver               8.8.8.8;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "img-src https: data:; upgrade-insecure-requests";

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location ~ ^/(commands|components|config|controllers|models|vendor|views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    location /pgadmin/ {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5050/;
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host     $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server   $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        proxy_redirect     off;
    }

    location / {
        # root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:12000/;
        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host     $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Server   $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        proxy_redirect     default;
    }
}
```

The idea is to open, say, the pgadmin location (proxied internally in Docker nginx as http://pgadmin on port 5050) to the big world via HTTPS as follows: `https://my-domain.site/pgadmin` But somehow the given config just doesn't work! What am I doing wrong?